# How to enclose a multiline command within an until-do loop in YAML

Tags: shell, yaml

I need to use an until-do loop in the "script" section of a YAML file, and the command in the `until` clause visually benefits from being broken into multiple lines:

```yaml
- >
  helm upgrade $(...) /helm/charts/ -f .(...)
    --install
    --set host=(...)
    --set tag=(...)
    --set image=(...)
    --namespace (...)
```

I've tried using this formatting to enclose the `helm upgrade` command within an until-do loop:

```yaml
- >
      until helm upgrade $FOO helm/charts/ -f ./(...)
        --install
        --set imagePullSecret=(...)
        --set host=(...) --set tag=(...)
        --set image=(...)
        --namespace (...); do
          helm uninstall $FOO
          done
```

...which results in the errors:

```bash
(...): line 161: --install: command not found
(...): line 162: --set: command not found
(...): line 163: --set: command not found
(...): line 164: --set: command not found
(...): line 165: --namespace: command not found
Error: uninstall: Release not loaded: (...): release: not found
```

However, if I abandon efforts to make this more readable:

```yaml
 - >
   until helm upgrade foo helm/charts/ -f ./(...) --install --set imagePullSecret=(...) --set host=(...) --set tag=(...) --set image=(...) --namespace (...); do
        helm uninstall foo
        done
```

...the command runs as expected:

```bash
Release "bar" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
```

What is the correct way to enclose a multiline command within an until-do loop in YAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal block scalar (started with `>`) in YAML will fold line endings into spaces between consecutive non-empty lines… unless one of the lines is more indented than the base indentation of the scalar.

This has been designed so that something like

```yaml
>
  lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet

   * one
   * two
```

will be parsed as

```
"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n\n *one\n *two\n"
```

since the `*` symbols are more indented than the `lorem ipsum` line.

In your case, this means that if you want to break the command into multiple lines but want it parsed as a single line, you mustn't indent the continuation lines:

```yaml
- >
      until helm upgrade $FOO helm/charts/ -f ./(...)
      --install
      --set imagePullSecret=(...)
      --set host=(...) --set tag=(...)
      --set image=(...)
      --namespace (...); do
          helm uninstall $FOO
      done
```

You can indent the `helm uninstall` since it should be executed as separate command.

If you dislike this and want to indent the continuation lines, you need to escape the resulting newlines:

```yaml
- >
      until helm upgrade $FOO helm/charts/ -f ./(...) \
        --install \
        --set imagePullSecret=(...) \
        --set host=(...) --set tag=(...) \
        --set image=(...) \
        --namespace (...); do
          helm uninstall $FOO
      done
```